# jquery cookie - hoursToLive

Tags: jquery, cookies

i'm using the jquery cookie plugin. Everything works fine except the fact that I have no idea how to set an expiration-time for the cookie?

```
$.cookie('opt_visible', 'true');
```

the jquery-cookie documentation says:

> ## hoursToLive (DEPRECATED for expiresAt)

- NUMBER
- For how many hours should the cookie be valid? (Passing 0 means to delete the cookie at the end of the browser session--this is default. Negative values will delete the cookie, but you should use the del() method instead.)

That's exactly what I'd like to have. The cookie should be available as long as i'm browsing the site. As soon as i close the window or browsertab, the cookie should be deleted.

How can i implement this hoursToLive thingy to my mentioned line above?

Thank you

Comment: Seems your documentation is from a different plugin to the one you are actually using. There is a $.cookie plugin and a $.cookies plugin. Your example uses $.cookie but the documentation is from $.cookies documentation. See these links https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie   &    http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding you don't need to do anything at all. `hoursToLive` is deprecated but not removed yet. As 0 is the default for `hoursToLive` anyway the cookie will be removed when the browser is closed (**!not** when only the tab is closed but the browser remains open).

If you really need to remove the cookie when the tab is closed you could try attaching an event handler to the window unload event `jQuery(window).unload(...)` and inside that handler call the `del('...')` but that might not always work

---

If it's enough that the cookie expires after e.g. 1 hour you can simply pass in the `expiresAt` option when setting the cookie

```
expiresAt: new Date(new Date().getTime()+3600000) //now + 1h (60*60*1000)
```

Comment: The problem is: I want to load a certain overlay-div that lies on top of my website. It should only appear when the site is loaded the first time. This div is closable (it actually just hides if i click the closebutton). If I don't set a cookie and click for instance some internal link on my website the overlay-div gets shown again. So i want to set a cookie that lives until i close the window or tab. It would be also okay if the cookie lives for an hour or so. But i have no idea how to implement that!

Comment: Check expanded answer for 1h solution

Comment: expiresAt is not a valid option for the jquery cookie plugin, if you use it it will fall over and create a cookie which only lasts for the browser session. you should be using this date in expires: not expiresAt: see here for further info https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.rdoc